# Creating a new instance that updates others, Sequelize, NodeJs, Express, Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Nodejs, Express and Sequelize. I have a Postgres table that named Categories with a viewOrder field :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define(
        'Category',
        {
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            viewOrder: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            }
        },
        {}
    );
    return Category;
};
```

Inserting a new record may bring problems with that, because, if the existing records have view orders of, say, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], and the new record has an order view of 4, then the current 4 must be changed to 5, and the current 5 must be changed to 6

(I’m forcing this order views to be consecutive numbers, from the front-end side)

I guess that a simple Category.create won't suffice

Updating may also cause problems, if I want to change the record with viewOrder of 5, to a viewOrder of 3, then the records with view orders of 3 and 4, must also be changed, along with the one we are updating

How can I do that in Sequelize?

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an awful idea to rely on frontend to maintain unique values of `viewOrder`. The same goes for `Sequelize`. The most reliable way is to generate such unique values by PostgreSQL itself either creating a sequence (if you don't need to reuse generated values) or adding a trigger(s) on Category  table.

Comment: All I'm looking for is a way of doing increments in bulk with sequelize, say, all instances that have viewOrder >= 4, increment it by 1, for example. I think of cycles, but is there a bulk way?

Comment: And, this solution has to work in reverse order. using the same previous example, increment by 1 all elements that have a viewOrder >= 4, but starting by the last one, in order to maintain uniqueness

Comment: Then you just need to call Category.update({ viewOrder: Sequelize.literal('(viewOrder + 1)')}, { where: <where clause>})

Comment: Hi Anatoly, I type Category.update({viewOrder: Sequelize.literal('viewOrder + 1')},{where: {viewOrder: {[Op.gte]: newViewOrder}}});, and it tells me that error: column "vieworder" does not exist. Where is this vieworder?

Comment: Look in a table how exactly this column is named because in Sequelize.literal you should use real column names from a table and not those you defined in the model.

Comment: Yes, and I changed it to Category.update({ viewOrder: Sequelize.literal('Categories.viewOrder + 1') },{ where: { viewOrder: { [Op.gte]: newViewOrder } } }); It doesn't throw the error, but doesn't do anything

Comment: Because you probably don't have any records where `viewOrder` is greater or equal to `newViewOrder `

Comment: Yes, there a records that satisfy it. In fact, I changed the reference of newViewOrder directly to 4, for testing purposes, still doesn't work

Comment: I DID IT. Thank you Anatoly. I typed the literal as: Sequelize.literal('"Categories"."viewOrder" + 1')

Comment: The only thing that I had to change was that the viewOrder field was also unique, then, when it worked, it threw the unique violation error. If there were some way of setting deferred to true or something